# Getting a function from an express server and running it in a webpage via a script tag

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

How do you return a function from an express server and run it in a browser?

I have hosted a function on Google Cloud Platform (Cloud Functions) and want to run it in a web application via a `script` tag. The function is in Nodejs 16 and can be called via https, and is a simple hello world example:

```js
exports.helloWorld = () => {
  const widget = console.log("This is a widget");
  return widget();
}
```

However, it seems as though I cannot call it that way, because I get an `Error: could not handle the request` and a 500 status message each time I try to hit the endpoint.

I want to be able to embed this function on a website via something like:

```html
<script src="https://example.com/function-name"/>
```

How can I achieve that?

Comment: Does the curl on the function work unitary?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by this? Do you mean jsut do a curl request in the cli? I only tried via a browser and postman, and both failed.

Comment: Yes, try the function url with a simple curl, to test it unary, and to avoid any browser/postman side effet

Answer (score 1):

It seems that your Cloud Function is malformed. When you create a Cloud Function you have to return a status code otherwise the Cloud Function will timeout waiting for the return status code (throwing the 500 error you had).

If I guess correctly what you want to do is call an external script from the Cloud Function, you can use the next code:

```
exports.helloWorld = (req, res) => {
  let message = 'alert("Hello world from CF")'; //Or any js code script here
  res.status(200).send(message);
};
```

And call it from the HTML page like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://zone-project-id.cloudfunctions.net/helloworld"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- the content goes here -->
        Hello world!
    </body>
</html>
```